# Is there a tag for referencing in which movies/games a track was featured?

Tags: classification, digital-audio

I want to tag in which works (like movies and games) my collected tracks were featured.

For example, [Ben Howard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Howard)’s *Oats in the Water* was featured in an episode of [*The Walking Dead*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walking_Dead_%28TV_series%29). So I want to tag it like

```
<tag-name-here>: The Walking Dead
```

I’d do the same with the actual soundtracks to *The Walking Dead*, and all other musical works that get featured in this series. This then allows me to filter my collection to only list these tracks. While using playlists for this purpose might work, too, I prefer having this data saved in the music files, as this makes migration, backups, and moving/renaming files easier.

It’s not a `genre`, and I don’t want to change the `title` or `album` for that, of course. Currently I’m using `comment`, but this gets confusing if I want to add an actual comment, and it doesn’t allow for easy searching/filtering.

Is there an applicable tag defined somewhere? Or do I have to come up with my own tag for this?

Comment: This should probably be in meta, right?

Comment: @DJAftershock: Why? This is not about tagging questions but music ;)

Comment: I changed the tags because `tagging` doesn't seem too useful where `classification` seems more appropriate and so does `digital-audio` for questions about digital music and file formats. We may eventually want each format as a separate tag, but for now I think just `digital-audio` is fine.

Comment: Another thing @unor, some tracks may appear in tons of movies, so in this case, you'll need a special tag that allows multiple answers.

Answer (score 2):

According to [The Library of Congress](http://blogs.loc.gov/thesignal/2013/01/name-that-tune-adding-labels-and-descriptions-into-your-audio-files/) in 2013 (but it is likely still available):

> **There is no single official metadata standard or container yet to which all audio software and hardware makers adhere**, though the closest thing is a popular informal container called **ID3**, which is most often associated with MP3s. An online search for “ID3 tag tool” will turn up a lot of free and useful tools that’ll enable you to see and edit the headers of MP3 files.

I didn't see a tag like the one you are looking for in the [ID3 standard](http://id3.org/Home) or supported tags by iTunes and VLC, so maybe you could create one with a tool you will find online or reuse an unused tag. You may want to create a *Soundtrack* tag (to be not confused with soundtrack genre), where you can specify which track featured in which movie when needed.